# Error : 403 Unknown client JAVA

Tags: pushtopic

I have a salesforce developer account . I was trying to use push topic notifcation via Java code as explained in https://github.com/SalesforceSFDC/Salesforce-Streaming-API/blob/master/StreamingClientExample.java

I keep getting 403 : Unknown client .

```
Login successful!
Server URL: https://na50.salesforce.com
Session ID= <Valid session id> 
Waiting for handshake
[CHANNEL:META_HANDSHAKE]: {"minimumVersion":"1.0","clientId":"24ttuvav30dn82h1oxp","supportedConnectionTypes":["long-polling"],"channel":"/meta/handshake","id":"1","version":"1.0","successful":true}
[CHANNEL:META_HANDSHAKE]: id 24ttuvav30dn82h1oxp
[CHANNEL:META_CONNECT]: {"clientId":"24ttuvav30dn82h1oxp","advice":{"reconnect":"handshake","interval":500},"channel":"/meta/connect","id":"2","error":"403::Unknown client","successful":false}
[CHANNEL:META_CONNECT]: id 24ttuvav30dn82h1oxp
Error during CONNECT: 403::Unknown client
Exiting...
Error:  CHANNEL:META_CONNECT Error : 403::Unknown client
```

Any pointers how to resolve this , will be helpful